# Vector extension for p-divisible group

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, algebraic-number-theory, abelian-varieties

#### Background:

I am trying to understand a proof of Messing's book at Page 120. My goal it to understand the universal vector extention.

#### Reference:

Messing, The crystals associated to Barsotti-Tate groups. Page 120. Attached pictures:

[image]

#### Statement:

Let $G$ be a p-divisible group over $R$, such that $p^n=0$ in $R$. Consider the exact sequence of group schemes

$$
1\rightarrow G[p^n]\rightarrow G \rightarrow G\rightarrow 1
$$

The map $G\rightarrow G$ is given by multiplying $p^n$, Apply the functor 
$$
Hom(-,\mathbb{G}_a)
$$

we obtain a long exact sequence

$$
1\rightarrow Hom(G,\mathbb{G}_a)\rightarrow Hom(G,\mathbb{G}_a)\rightarrow Hom(G[p^n],\mathbb{G}_a)\rightarrow Ext^1(G,\mathbb{G}_a)\rightarrow Ext^1(G,\mathbb{G}_a)
$$

If I understood correct, $Hom(G,\mathbb{G}_a)$ is the space of functions $f$ on $G$ such that 
$f(gh)=f(g)+f(h)$

The map $\phi:Hom(G,\mathbb{G}_a)\rightarrow Hom(G,\mathbb{G}_a)$ is induced by 
$$
\phi(f)(g)=f([p^n]g)=p^nf(g)
$$
Since $p^n=0$ we have $Hom(G,\mathbb{G}_a)\rightarrow Hom(G,\mathbb{G}_a)$ is a zero map.

#### Questions:

**Question 0**: Anything wrong in the statements?

**Question 1**: then how can the sequence $1\rightarrow Hom(G,\mathbb{G}_a)\rightarrow Hom(G,\mathbb{G}_a)$ become exact??? It is exact if and only if $Hom(G,\mathbb{G}_a)=0$. Messing said the connection map $Hom(G[p^n],\mathbb{G}_a)\rightarrow Ext^1(G,\mathbb{G}_a)$ is an isomorphism, an necessary condition for it to be true is also $Hom(G,\mathbb{G}_a)=0$

But I am pretty sure $Hom(G,\mathbb{G}_a)\neq 0$ in some cases (height 2 dimension 1, since $Hom(G,\mathbb{G}_a)$ is the tangent space of $G^*$)

**Question 2**: How to discribe the map $Hom(G[p^n],\mathbb{G}_a)\rightarrow Ext^1(G,\mathbb{G}_a)$ explicitly? That is, given an element in $Hom(G[p^n],\mathbb{G}_a)$, how can you define extention by construct $E$ sits in the following exact sequence?
$$
1\rightarrow \mathbb{G}_a\rightarrow E\rightarrow G\rightarrow 1
$$

Comment: 1. There are no nonzero maps from a $p$-divisible group to a $p^N$-torsion group. 2. By pushout of $1\to G[p^n]\to G\to G\to 1$ along the given homomorphism (up to sign, at least).

Comment: Thanks Piotr, I also figured out, Hom(G,G_a) should be 0. But currently I am most confuse how to do push out for p-divisible group, because I am not sure whether I can do quotient of p-divisible group by any subgroup scheme.